# simple card number verification into a form LUHN algorithm

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to make a form that validates a name email and credit card number. if the fields are invalid than an ever shows and prompt the user to re enter their details. however for validating the credit card number I need to use the LUHN algorithm. I  have the code needed to verify the credit card field however it is separate and I am not sure on how to integrate it with the validation of the other two forms. The other two forms are validated and an error is shown if they are wrong however i cant get the error to show up for the credit card field.

Thank you,

My code for the LUHN checker:

```js
$('#cc').on('input', function(){
  if (checkLuhn($('#cc').val())) {
    field.setCustomValidity("");
  } else {
    field.setCustomValidity("Invalid field.");
  }
});
```

My whole program:

```js
(function () {
  "use strict";
  /*
   * Form Validation
   */

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom validation styles to
  const forms = document.querySelectorAll(".needs-validation");
  const result = document.getElementById("result");
  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach(function (form) {
    form.addEventListener(
      "submit",
      function (event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity() ) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();

          form.querySelectorAll(":invalid")[0].focus();
        } else {
          /*
           * Form Submission using fetch()
           */

          const formData = new FormData(form);
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
          const object = {};
          formData.forEach((value, key) => {
            object[key] = value;
          });
          const json = JSON.stringify(object);
          result.innerHTML = "Please wait...";

          fetch("https://api.web3forms.com/submit", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              Accept: "application/json"
            },
            body: json
          })
            .then(async (response) => {
              let json = await response.json();
              if (response.status == 200) {
                result.innerHTML = json.message;
                result.classList.remove("text-gray-500");
                result.classList.add("text-green-500");
              } else {
                console.log(response);
                result.innerHTML = json.message;
                result.classList.remove("text-gray-500");
                result.classList.add("text-red-500");
              }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
              result.innerHTML = "Something went wrong!";
            })
            .then(function () {
              form.reset();
              form.classList.remove("was-validated");
              setTimeout(() => {
                result.style.display = "none";
              }, 5000);
            });
        }
        form.classList.add("was-validated");
      },
      false
    );
  });
})();

$('#cc').on('input', function(){
  if (checkLuhn($('#cc').val())) {
    field.setCustomValidity("");
  } else {
    field.setCustomValidity("Invalid field.");
  }
});

function checkLuhn(value) {
  // remove all non digit characters
  var value = value.replace(/\D/g, '');
  var sum = 0;
  var shouldDouble = false;
  // loop through values starting at the rightmost side
  for (var i = value.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var digit = parseInt(value.charAt(i));
    
    if (shouldDouble) {
      if ((digit *= 2) > 9) digit -= 9;
    }

    sum += digit;
    shouldDouble = !shouldDouble;
  }
  return (sum % 10) == 0;
}
```

```css
.invalid-feedback,
.empty-feedback {
  display: none;
}

.was-validated :placeholder-shown:invalid ~ .empty-feedback {
  display: block;
}

.was-validated :not(:placeholder-shown):invalid ~ .invalid-feedback {
  display: block;
}

.is-invalid,
.was-validated :invalid {
  border-color: #dc3545;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.4/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 
    =======================================================================

    This is a working contact form. To receive email, 
    Replace YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_HERE with your actual Access Key.

    Create Access Key here  https://web3forms.com/

    =======================================================================
 -->

<div class="flex items-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900">
  <div class="container mx-auto">
    <div class="max-w-xl mx-auto my-10 bg-white p-5 rounded-md shadow-sm">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="my-3 text-3xl font-semibold text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200">
          Contact Us
        </h1>
        <p class="text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-400">
          Fill up the form below to send us a message.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="m-7">
        <form action="https://api.web3forms.com/submit" method="POST" id="form" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
          <input type="hidden" name="access_key" value="YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_HERE" />
          <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="New Submission from Web3Forms" />
          <input type="checkbox" name="botcheck" id="" style="display: none;" />

          <div class="flex mb-6 space-x-4">
            <div class="w-full md:w-1/2">
              <label for="fname" class="block mb-2 text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" id="first_name" placeholder="John" required class="w-full px-3 py-2 placeholder-gray-300 border-2 border-gray-200 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-100 focus:border-indigo-300" />
              <div class="empty-feedback invalid-feedback text-red-400 text-sm mt-1">
                Please provide your first name.
              </div>
            </div>
            
          </div>

          <div class="flex mb-6 space-x-4">
            <div class="w-full md:w-1/2">
              <label for="email" class="block mb-2 text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400">Email Address</label>
              <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="you@company.com" required class="w-full px-3 py-2 placeholder-gray-300 border-2 border-gray-200 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-100 focus:border-indigo-300" />
              <div class="empty-feedback text-red-400 text-sm mt-1">
                Please provide your email address.
              </div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback text-red-400 text-sm mt-1">
                Please provide a valid email address.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
                <div class="flex mb-6 space-x-4">
                  
            <div class="w-full md:w-1/2">
              <label for="email" class="block mb-2 text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400">Credit Card Number</label>
              <input type="text" id="cc" type="text" 
placeholder="XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX" required class="w-full px-3 py-2 placeholder-gray-300 border-2 border-gray-200 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-100 focus:border-indigo-300" />
                
              <div class="empty-feedback text-red-400 text-sm mt-1">
                Please provide your credit card number.
              </div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback text-red-400 text-sm mt-1">
                Please provide a valid credit card number.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="mb-6">
            <button type="submit" class="w-full px-3 py-4 text-white bg-indigo-500 rounded-md focus:bg-indigo-600 focus:outline-none">
              Send Message
            </button>
          </div>
          <p class="text-base text-center text-gray-400" id="result"></p>
        </form>
          
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store an HTML element in the `field` variable.

Also you had some typos in your HTML code.

The snippet below should work :

```js
(function () {
  "use strict";
  /*
   * Form Validation
   */

  // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom validation styles to
  const forms = document.querySelectorAll(".needs-validation");
  const result = document.getElementById("result");
  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach(function (form) {
    form.addEventListener(
      "submit",
      function (event) {
        if (!form.checkValidity() ) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();

          form.querySelectorAll(":invalid")[0].focus();
        } else {
          /*
           * Form Submission using fetch()
           */

          const formData = new FormData(form);
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
          const object = {};
          formData.forEach((value, key) => {
            object[key] = value;
          });
          const json = JSON.stringify(object);
          result.innerHTML = "Please wait...";

          fetch("https://api.web3forms.com/submit", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              Accept: "application/json"
            },
            body: json
          })
            .then(async (response) => {
              let json = await response.json();
              if (response.status == 200) {
                result.innerHTML = json.message;
                result.classList.remove("text-gray-500");
                result.classList.add("text-green-500");
              } else {
                console.log(response);
                result.innerHTML = json.message;
                result.classList.remove("text-gray-500");
                result.classList.add("text-red-500");
              }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
              result.innerHTML = "Something went wrong!";
            })
            .then(function () {
              form.reset();
              form.classList.remove("was-validated");
              setTimeout(() => {
                result.style.display = "none";
              }, 5000);
            });
        }
        form.classList.add("was-validated");
      },
      false
    );
  });
})();

$('#cc').on('input', function(){
  const field = document.querySelector('#cardContainer input')
  if (checkLuhn($('#cc').val())) {
    field.setCustomValidity("");
  } else {
    field.setCustomValidity("Invalid field.");
  }
});

function checkLuhn(value) {
  // accept only digits, dashes or spaces
    if (/[^0-9-\s]+/.test(value)) return false;

// The Luhn Algorithm. It's so pretty.
    var nCheck = 0, nDigit = 0, bEven = false;
    value = value.replace(/\D/g, "");

    for (var n = value.length - 1; n >= 0; n--) {
        var cDigit = value.charAt(n),
            nDigit = parseInt(cDigit, 10);

        if (bEven) {
            if ((nDigit *= 2) > 9) nDigit -= 9;
        }

        nCheck += nDigit;
        bEven = !bEven;
    }

    return (nCheck % 10) == 0;
}
```

```css
.invalid-feedback,
.empty-feedback {
  display: none;
}

.was-validated :placeholder-shown:invalid ~ .empty-feedback {
  display: block;
}

.was-validated :not(:placeholder-shown):invalid ~ .invalid-feedback {
  display: block;
}

.is-invalid,
.was-validated :invalid {
  border-color: #dc3545;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.0.4/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 
    =======================================================================

    This is a working contact form. To receive email, 
    Replace YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_HERE with your actual Access Key.

    Create Access Key here  https://web3forms.com/

    =======================================================================
 -->

<div class="flex items-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900">
  <div class="container mx-auto">
    <div class="max-w-xl mx-auto my-10 bg-white p-5 rounded-md shadow-sm">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="my-3 text-3xl font-semibold text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-200">
          Contact Us
        </h1>
        <p class="text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-400">
          Fill up the form below to send us a message.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="m-7">
        <form action="https://api.web3forms.com/submit" method="POST" id="form" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
          <input type="hidden" name="access_key" value="YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_HERE" />
          <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="New Submission from Web3Forms" />
          <input type="checkbox" name="botcheck" id="" style="display: none;" />

          <div class="flex mb-6 space-x-4">
            <div class="w-full md:w-1/2">
              <label for="fname" class="block mb-2 text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" id="first_name" placeholder="John" required class="w-full px-3 py-2 placeholder-gray-300 border-2 border-gray-200 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-100 focus:border-indigo-300" />
              <div class="empty-feedback invalid-feedback text-red-400 text-sm mt-1">
                Please provide your first name.
              </div>
            </div>
            
          </div>

          <div class="flex mb-6 space-x-4">
            <div class="w-full md:w-1/2">
              <label for="email" class="block mb-2 text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400">Email Address</label>
              <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="you@company.com" required class="w-full px-3 py-2 placeholder-gray-300 border-2 border-gray-200 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-100 focus:border-indigo-300" />
              <div class="empty-feedback text-red-400 text-sm mt-1">
                Please provide your email address.
              </div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback text-red-400 text-sm mt-1">
                Please provide a valid email address.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
                <div class="flex mb-6 space-x-4">
                  
            <div id="cardContainer" class="w-full md:w-1/2">
              <label for="email" class="block mb-2 text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-400">Credit Card Number</label>
              <input type="text" id="cc" type="text" 
placeholder="XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX"  required class="w-full px-3 py-2 placeholder-gray-300 border-2 border-gray-200 rounded-md focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-100 focus:border-indigo-300" />
                
              <div class="empty-feedback text-red-400 text-sm mt-1">
                Please provide your credit card number.
              </div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback text-red-400 text-sm mt-1">
                Please provide a valid credit card number.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="mb-6">
            <button type="submit" class="w-full px-3 py-4 text-white bg-indigo-500 rounded-md focus:bg-indigo-600 focus:outline-none">
              Send Message
            </button>
          </div>
          <p class="text-base text-center text-gray-400" id="result"></p>
        </form>
          
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```